# Sed: replace last dot

Tags: regex, sed

How to replace the last matching `dot`?

for example, I'd like to change test.jpg to test.th.jpg

what I've tried:

```
echo "test.jpg" | sed 's@[^\.]*$@\.th.@g'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ echo "test.jpg" | sed 's/\.\([^.]*\)$/.th.\1/'
```

It gives:

```
test.th.jpg
```

Explanation:

```
\.    literal dot
\(    start capturing group
[^.]  any character except dot
*     zero or more
\)    close capturing group
$     end of line
```

In the replacement `\1` replaces the content of the first capturing group :)

Comment: sed's regex is greedy, which we could make use of. so the `\.` could be saved, actually if you take a look your replacement part, you had the `dot` again.

Answer (score 2):

```
kent$  sed 's/[^.]*$/th.&/' <<<"test.jpg"    
test.th.jpg
```

or

```
kent$  sed 's/.*\./&th./' <<<"test.jpg" 
test.th.jpg
```

or

```
kent$  awk -F. -v OFS="." '$NF="th."$NF' <<< "test.jpg"
test.th.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `awk`, prepend "th." to the last field

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}$NF="th."$NF' <<< "test.jpg"
test.th.jpg
```

Comment: Can you explain `$NF="th."$NF` part?

Comment: `$NF` is the value after the last dot, in this case it's `jpg`, so `"th."$NF` will be `th.jpg`, `$NF="th."$NF` is to update the last field to `th.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Using pure bash

```
$ str="test.abc.jpg"

$ echo ${str%.*}.th.jpg
test.abc.th.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby on your system

```
echo test.jpg | ruby -e 'x=gets.split(".");x.insert(-2,"th"); puts x.join(".")'
```